# How can i filter in telerik grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik

I am working on telerik grid in NopCommerce with some customization. I want to achieve filtering in my one column named PercentageCompleted. Now how can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post your view code with the Grid definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at the following example for Grid on Telerik Demo site for MVC Extension:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid

we call this demo the first look of Telerik MVC Extension based Grid. In this example the grid binds to order table of Northwind database. Here is the Razor View Code:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ContactName).Width(200);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
            columns.Bound(o => o.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(120);
        })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => 
        {
            dataBinding.Server().Select("FirstLook", "Grid", new { ajax = ViewData["ajax"] });
            dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_FirstLook", "Grid").Enabled((bool)ViewData["ajax"]);
        })
        .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(true))
        .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true))
        .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled(true))
        .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(true))
        .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Enabled(true))
        .Footer((true)
)
```

As you can see, we need to first set the global switch

```
.Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(true))
```

which tells the Grid whether it is filterable or not. Once we turn this switch on, all the columns in the column collection will; by default get a filter on them.

In your case you wanted to enable the filter only one column. In order to achieve that, you will need to manually turn off the filtering capability on those columns where you dont need it. for e.g. in the above code i want to disable the filter option on OrderID and OrderDate column. The code to achieve that is as follows:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Width(100).Filterable(false);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ContactName).Width(200);
            columns.Bound(o => o.ShipAddress);
            columns.Bound(o => o.OrderDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Width(120).Filterable(false);
        })
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => 
        {
            dataBinding.Server().Select("FirstLook", "Grid", new { ajax = ViewData["ajax"] });
            dataBinding.Ajax().Select("_FirstLook", "Grid").Enabled((bool)ViewData["ajax"]);
        })
        .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(true))
        .Sortable(sorting => sorting.Enabled(true))
        .Pageable(paging => paging.Enabled(true))
        .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(true))
        .Groupable(grouping => grouping.Enabled(true))
        .Footer((true)
)
```

Hope this answers your question.

Lohith (Tech Evangelist, Telerik India)

Comment: Thank you very much...And please can you suggest me what will be the code for that? What code should be in the controller?

Comment: you can look at the source code of the demo at http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid - you will get the view and the controller codes in that demo page

Answer (score 2):

Add .Filterable to the grid definition like so

```
@Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("Grid")
        .Filterable()
```

This makes all columns with simple data types filterable.  To specify columns, add

```
.Filterable(true)
```

or

```
.Filterable(false)
```

to each column definition